# Missing backslashes in filename using C#

Tags: c#, string

I have a string literal as follows:

```
string filename = @"C:\myfolder\myfile.jpg";
```

When I use File.Exists(filename) it works most of the time but sometimes I get an error saying the following file doesn't exist:

```
C:myfoldermyfile.jpg
```

Something seems to strip the backslashes out of the filename. This code is sometimes accessed via an ajax request.

Does anyone know why/how this could be happening?

Edit:

Here is a more detailed version of the code.

```
public class Feeds {

    public static string ftpDir = @"C:\website\Feeds\";

}

public class Feed {

    public static void run(string name) {

        if (!Directory.Exists(Feeds.ftpDir + name)){ 

            Response.Write("Feed doesn't exist '" + Feeds.ftpDir + name + "'"); 

            return; 

        }

        //run feed...

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post a small, complete example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Can you make ftpDir a const? At least then you would know that it wasn't being modified at runtime.

Comment: In your example, does "name" contain only a filename and not a path? And sometimes Feeds.ftpDir + name evaluates to: C:websiteFeedsFileName.Ext ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most likely you didn't use `Path.Combine` to combine path with file name. You should never concatenate path elements using the + operator.

Comment: I would give `Path.Combine` a try, it is exactly meant for this type of operations.

Comment: This sounds like it could fix the problem. I just don't understand how it could work sometimes and not others. I'll try this thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Probably you simply missed an `@` symbol in front of one of your literals somewhere - then `@"C:\mydir\myfile.txt"` would work, but `"C:\mydir\myfile.txt"` would not.

You probably know, but just in case: a string prefixed with an @ isn't escaped as usual (i.e. a `\n` sequence then really means backslash-lowercase n and not newline.  It's handy for including raw newlines and other stuff in source, and particularly handy if you want to represent something with lots of backslashes as content (e.g. regexes).

Answer (score 0):

The backslash character in C# is the escape character, so you're "escaping" the `m` character twice. You would need a literal `\\` everywhere you want a `\` in the string.

For your use case, System.IO.Path.Combine doesn't seem necessary since it's a static path, but when you are building paths from, say, two strings, one with a folder name and the other a filename, it's the best way, and it's platform-independent.

(*Edit:* since you are using the `@` character prefix, any stripping of the `\` isn't happening in the compiler.)

Comment: he's using literals prefixes with `@` - those don't need or support escaping with backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

the backslash is an escape character, so after you need to put 2 in a row to get the actual character to show up in your string. you would need to do "C:\myfolder\myfile.jpg"

Comment: sorry im new to the site, dont know how to format it propperly, it should be: C:\\myfolder\\myfile.jpg

Answer (score 0):

The `Directory.Exists(string)` call is returning false, because you are passing it a file path rather than a directory path.

I don't know what's stripping the backslashes on the display, unless it has something to do with AJAX.